# Setting FSO to FileSystemObject vs Scripting.FileSystemObject

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject, reference-library

I just had one of those moments where you step out of the weeds and examine your code and ask yourself "why did I do that?"

I have a script that creates a folder with several subfolders and files using the `FileSystemObject`. Everything works, but I guess I've been varying the way I set my `fso` variables.

My project uses the the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library` reference so that I can use early binding (even though I found several instances of `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"`), which is silly for this project). Perhaps it's because I've based a lot of my code from examples online, but I've been setting these fso variables in one of two ways:

```
Set FSo = New FileSystemObject

Set FSo = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

What is the difference between these? Does it matter which I use, or is one used only in certain cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between these is that the latter disambiguates the `FileSystemObject` to belong to `Scripting` and not to something else.

If you had your own class named `FileSystemObject` in that workbook, the latter would be required to specify you are creating the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and not `Yourworkbook.FileSystemObject`.

Similarly, if you had a reference to some other external library that also featured a class named `FileSystemObject`, it would resolve that ambiguity too. That is why there are up/down arrows in the Add Reference dialog - they decide which library wins in the case of a clashed name and no explicit disambiguation from the coder.

A common case in VBA where the disambiguation is needed is working with Word and Excel object models at the same time. Both have a class called `Range`, and you often need to specify whether you want `Word.Range` or `Excel.Range` this time.

If you don't have any such conflicting names, it makes no difference for you, apart from maybe making it a tad easier for the future reader to recall that `FileSystemObject` is that thing from `Scripting`.